# Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, xml

I have the following code:

activity_main2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".Main2Activity">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_items" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main2Activity:

```
package asus.example.com.oop;

import android.os.Bundle; import android.app.Activity;

public class Main2Activity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

}
```

nav_items.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/home24"
        android:title="@string/home"
        />

    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/notifications24"
        android:title="@string/notifications"
        />

    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/person24"
        android:title="@string/account"
        />
</menu>
```

And when I run the program I have the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{asus.example.com.oop/asus.example.com.oop.Main2Activity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML
>   file line #9: Error inflating class
>   android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView Caused by:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML
>   file line #9: Error inflating class
>   android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView Caused by:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error
>   inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

I don't know, why i have this problem. I added line `compile 'com.android.support:design'` to build gradle, but it still doesn't work. What's the matter?

Comment: Try `extends AppCompatActivity` if you want to use support classes

Comment: Use same version of appcompat library and design support library in your app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use AppCompat features your activity needs to be extending `AppCompatActivity`

replace

```
public class Main2Activity extends Activity
```

with

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity
```

Comment: and if i have theme which isn't AppCompat can i fix my problem without changing it?

Comment: You have to use AppCompact activity to use AppCompact features. Try it out if it doesnt work use an AppCompact theme